# Development prob with SBApplication

Tags: iphone, objective-c, sdk, ios5

```
SBApplication* application = [[%c(SBApplicationController)

sharedInstance] applicationWithDisplayIdentifier:@"APPLICATION_ID"];

[application contextHostView];
```

This code keep make my iDevice crash on iOS5 does anybody know why it is crashing or any example code on how to use contextHostView.

Comment: Could you share the error from your error log?  If you remove %c does it work?

Comment: When i remove the %c it has a error, but the crash logs explains it..    http://pastebin.com/HEFC8vcg - Log                                            I use Theos man and I compile on the iDevice itself...

Answer (score 0):

There's no contextHostView in UIApplication anymore. Try this:

```
UIView *contextHostView = [[app contextHostManager] _realContextHostViewWhichIReallyNeedToAccessAndIKnowWhatImDoingISwear];
```